# How to integrate memcached with MarkLogic?

Tags: memcached, marklogic

I want to integrate memcached with MarkLogic and use it as a module in XQuery. How to work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to integrate such tools within MarkLogic itself. You normally want to apply such tools in a more transparant way. Put it as a reverse proxy in front of MarkLogic. Or if you want to use it to cache HTTP call made from within MarkLogic to other services, then put them in front of those services.

For some more background, I refer to this blog article about using HTTPD as reverse proxy. Not the most recent article, but it touches the basic concepts, and it would still work I think:

https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2004-09-cisapache

I also searched for something more specific to memcached (in front of MarkLogic), but couldn't find anything. Then again, it would be implemented as an ordinary reverse proxy. There should be plenty resources on internet that discuss Reverse Proxying..

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually, what does a reverse proxy mean. How to configure memcached as reverse proxy in front of MarkLogic?   Also, MarkLogic provides its own caching. If I use distributed caching it will be faster than MarkLogic caching?

Comment: Are you experiencing slowness with MarkLogic server?  It's pretty blazing fast in general.  Perhaps you can re-frame your question with details about specific problems you're encountering that are driving you to take on a potentially complex caching layer integration.

Comment: Yeah MarkLogic is blazing fast. But sometimes big caching are causing more memory utilization. So I want to use a distributed caching system. How to configure it with MarkLogic?